# Where should I save TestNG configuration test files

Tags: java, testng, maven-archetype

I have a question about the TestNG configuration files and Maven project structure, I would like know the best practices to save the configuration files.

E.g. I have use a  `testing.xml` is a file which uses several classes to create a Suite. If I use the [java application archetype of maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/simple.html), where is the best place to save the xml file (`testing.xml`)?. I have taken a look to [Maven standar directories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), but I do not find anything about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

src/test/resources

you can create a folder test-suites here and have different suite xml's here.

Comment: I thought so. In a hand, this folder it should be use for saving the resources necessary to run the test. In this case, the aforementioned xml define a suite, so I think are different targets. In the other hand, I need to put in any folder, and this is the best candidate (like you say me)